# Issue joining multiple tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT    taxi.id as id,name,
  SUM(storico_pagamenti.importo) AS pagamentitotali,
  SUM(CASE WHEN storico_pagamenti.data <= '$timestop' AND storico_pagamenti.data >=     '$timestart' THEN storico_pagamenti.importo ELSE 0 END) AS pagamentimese,
  SUM(storico_fatture.importo) AS fatturetotali,
  SUM(CASE WHEN storico_fatture.data <= '$timestop' AND storico_fatture.data >= '$timestart' THEN storico_fatture.importo ELSE 0 END) AS fatturemese,
  COUNT(giornifermi.registrazione) as giornifermitotali,
  SUM(CASE WHEN giornifermi.data <= '$timestop' AND giornifermi.data >= '$timestart' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS giornifermimese
FROM taxi 
  LEFT JOIN storico_pagamenti ON taxi.id = storico_pagamenti.id_taxi
  LEFT JOIN storico_fatture ON storico_pagamenti.id_taxi=storico_fatture.id_taxi
  LEFT JOIN giornifermi ON storico_fatture.id_taxi=giornifermi.id_taxi
WHERE taxi.categoria='cv'
GROUP BY  taxi.id;
```

My mysql skills aren't enough for this query... can't understand where is the problem. The part that is not working is this

```
SUM(CASE WHEN giornifermi.data <= '$timestop' AND giornifermi.data >= '$timestart' THEN 1
ELSE 0 END) AS giornifermimese
```

which I expected to give me the count of the rows of giornifermi.data between two dates submitted

and this other part:

```
COUNT(giornifermi.registrazione) as giornifermitotali
```

which I expected to give me the count of all the rows in `giornifermi.registrazione` column

Is this because of the join? Or is it a problem in the two parts of the query?

EDIT-----------------------------------------
I've related now all the tables "ON" the same referrer taxi.id setting it equal to the variable id_taxi of the other tables and now I get the values but wrong. After the suggestion of @Twelf I've tried to comment the "GROUP BY taxi.id" and try select *. I've seen the problem now is that results are multiplied. Example If i have three rows in giornifermi, they became 6, if i have 2 rows in storico_pagamenti, It copies me again the three rows for each row in storico_pagamenti. in Don't have any idea of how to fix that but knowing the problem is better than nothing

EDIT------------------------------------------
Fixed by adding a subquery after the left join, instead of joining the whole table of giornifermi i've created there a brand new table to correct the data without duplicates

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
taxi.id as i,
COUNT(giornifermi.registrazione) as giornifermitotali,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN giornifermi.data <= '$timestop' AND giornifermi.data >= '$timestart' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) as giornifermimese
FROM taxi
LEFT JOIN giornifermi ON taxi.id=giornifermi.id_taxi
GROUP BY taxi.id
) AS NUOVATABELLA ON taxi.id=NUOVATABELLA.i
```

Comment: *not working* means? The syntax is correct.

Comment: What are the expected results and how do they compare with present results?

Comment: it doesn't give me the result expected, the count of the rows is always wrong

Comment: This is going to be tough to determine why your data is wrong since it is fine syntax-wise and we really don't know what your tables mean.

Comment: now the are all 0,
before i was trying to relate all the join to the first table like

     LEFT JOIN storico_pagamenti ON taxi.id = storico_pagamenti.id_taxi
 LEFT JOIN storico_fatture ON taxi.id=storico_fatture.id_taxi
 LEFT JOIN giornifermi ON taxi.id=giornifermi.id_taxi


and I got some numbers but wrong...

Comment: basically i need to retrieve the total number of records for each taxi.id, and the total number of records (of the id) within two dates both in the giornifermi table
and they are related through giornifermi.id_taxi

Comment: Not sure if I can give a solution, just some direction.  Try commenting out the group by and change the select statement to select *.   The results from that will be all the rows that the query is finding before the grouping is applied...take a single ID as an example and look at the records there.  Are they the rows you expect to see?  anything missing?  The issue you are having seems to be at that data level and not with the script...start troubleshooting your data

Comment: it was useful thanks. I've seen the numbers are wrong because rows in giornifermi table are multiplied for each entry in the other tables.Example If i have three rows in giornifermi, they became 6, if i have 2 rows in storico_pagamenti, It copies me again the three rows for each row in storico_pagamenti. in  Don't have any idea of how to fix that but knowing the problem is better than nothing

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell from your question, but basic trouble-shooting for 'wrong' counts:

1. If counts are too high and you have `JOIN`'s then it's likely insufficient `JOIN` criteria, IE Cartesian product.
2. If counts are too low, you're likely excluding records you don't mean to through `WHERE` criteria or restrictive `JOIN` criteria.
3. Select all fields for a small subset of records to help see where the discrepancy is coming from.

Update:

One or more of your tables has multiple entries for all/some `taxi_ID` values.

Run this for each table:

```
SELECT taxi_ID 
FROM storico_pagamenti 
GROUP BY taxi_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If any tables return records, look at them to see if there's another field you should be using in the `JOIN` to differentiate between the duplicates.

Comment: I've related all the tables "ON" the same referrer taxi.id and now I get the values but wrong.
After the suggestion of @Twelf I've tried to comment the "GROUP BY taxi.id" and try select *.
I've seen the problem now is that results are multiplied. Example If i have three rows in giornifermi, they became 6, if i have 2 rows in storico_pagamenti, It copies me again the three rows for each row in storico_pagamenti. in Don't have any idea of how to fix that but knowing the problem is better than nothing

Comment: Updated answer, should be able to find out which table is problematic easily.

Comment: what do you mean? of course I have a unique key for each record in those tables, but how can I add them to the join? the unique key column is call 'registrazione'

Comment: You just want to isolate which tables are resulting in duplicates, one of your tables has multiple records for the same `taxi_ID`, you need to  handle those, you can make a subquery for the offending table and group by taxi_ID, or you can add to your `JOIN` criteria so that only one record joins between each table.  Without seeing data I can't know which you need to do.

Comment: i fixed it creating a subquery after the left join to create a brand new table to join.

     LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
 taxi.id as i,
 COUNT(giornifermi.registrazione) as giornifermitotali,
 SUM(CASE
  WHEN giornifermi.data <= '$timestop' AND giornifermi.data >= '$timestart' THEN 1
   ELSE 0
  END) as giornifermimese
 FROM taxi
 LEFT JOIN giornifermi ON taxi.id=giornifermi.id_taxi
 GROUP BY taxi.id
 ) AS NUOVATABELLA ON taxi.id=NUOVATABELLA.i